# How can I switch the browser language for individual tests in Cypress?

Tags: vue.js, cypress, vue-i18n, quasar

I am writing a CI test that requires me to demonstrate that when, for example, the user has a French browser the page displays in French or falls back to English if no French translation is available.

The site uses Quasar and i18n to do the languages and works well but I need to show this using a test. I don't need to test every line of text just that it works. If you can think of a better way then I am open to suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if I'm wrong but I think you're looking for a local language switcher, there is some chrome extensions for that here is one I've already used : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-language-switcher/pmjbhfmaphnpbehdanbjphdcniaelfie?hl=en

Is it what you need for your tests ?

Comment: Good point, but not what I need. Quasar is detecting the language used from the browser and vue then uses the correct language string. I need to be able to trick the browser into thinking it is one language or another. 

The switcher is on the right path and would have been right if a human was testing, but I need to automate + with the browsers I use, all plugins are disabled.

I could probably change the config for the test browser but that would affect all tests and I need to be able to set the config for each test individually!

Comment: Ok, I've something else for you then. Do you know https://robotframework.org/#introduction ? I think it can do the trick

Comment: Thank you, this looks good but I am unfortunately restricted to using cypress - perhaps its not possible and I need to rethink my strategy or push back on the testable requirements!